# monad bind operation on a list not intuitive to follow

Tags: scala, scalaz

I find the `Option` Monad to be intuitive to understand, while `List` is not.

```
Some(1) >>= { x=>Some(x+1)}
 Ma -> a -> Mb -> Mb
```

if I extract value from Some(1) I know it is 1

but in the list case

```
 List(3,4,5) flatMap { x=> List(x,-x) }
```

if I extract value from List, what do I get ? how to make the understanding process intuitive

Comment: The monadic intuition behind lists is that a list-valued function returns many results at once. So what happens when you combine (sort of compose, but in the monadic world) two list-valued functions? The first one computes many results, and then feed all of them to the second function, which computes many results for each input. Hope this clarifies something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuition behind an `Option` or `Maybe` is actually very similar to `List` monad. The main difference is that `List` is non-deterministic - we don't know how many values we can get, when with `Option` it's always one on success and zero on failure. Empty list is considered a failure.

I think this [piece](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/monads.html) describes it quite well:

> For lists, monadic binding involves joining together a set of
>   calculations for each value in the list. When used with lists, the
>   signature of >>= becomes:
>
> (>>=)                   :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
>
> That is, given a list of a's and a function that maps an a onto a list
>   of b's, binding applies this function to each of the a's in the input
>   and returns all of the generated b's concatenated into a list.

And an [example](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#the-list-monad) of list implementation:

```
instance Monad [] where  
    return x = [x]  
    xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)  
    fail _ = []
```

Sorry for putting Haskell into Scala answer, but that was the resource I used to understand this stuff.

Scala's `flatMap` is not exactly Haskell's bind `>>=`, but quite close to it. So what does it all mean?:

Imagine a practical situation where you have a list of clients `List[Client]`, you can bind them to a single list of orders `List[Order]` that will be automatically flattened for you with `flatMap` or `>>=`. If you would use a `map` instead, you would get a `List[List[Order]]`. In practice you will provide the function for `>>=` to use, similarly how you provide a function to `fold` - you decide how data has to be generated/aggregated/etc. What bind does for you is to provide a general pattern for combining two monadic values and for each type of monads implementation will be unique.

You might prefer to look at it at as multiple levels of abstraction (from more general to less):

1. Monad has bind operation that will combine two monadic values into one: `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`.
2. `List` as a monad instance implements bind with something like this: `xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)` - map the function over all elements and concatenate results into a single list.
3. You provide an implementation of the function `f` for the bind function depending on your needs (the clients -> orders example).

Once you know how bind behaves for your monad instances (`List`, `Option`) you can think in terms of just using it and "forget" about actual implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by "failure" here?

"Empty list is considered a failure."

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. the implementation makes the operation clear to me. but without that I can still hardly say it's intuitive. also what about the `functor` monad etc... does that mean without the implementation it's not intuitive.

Comment: @drstevens usually a success is when we have a value, and a failure is when we don't. Empty option or empty list are failures. In practice it would mean that you failed to get some value when it was expected.

Comment: @zinking I guess since it all relates to Category Theory it's not very intuitive unless you familiar with it. Thus implementation or a practical example usually help to map it to familiar reasoning.